# parseInt on a string of 8 bits returns a negative value when the first bit is 1

Tags: java, parseint

I've got a huge string of bits (with some `\n` in it too) that I pass as a parameter to a method, which should isolate the bits 8 by 8, and convert them all to bytes using `parseInt()`.

Thing is, every time the substring of 8 bits starts with a 1, the resulting byte is a negative number. For example, the first substring is '10001101', and the resulting byte is -115. I can't seem to figure out why, can someone help? It works fine with other *substrings*.

Here's my code, if needed :

```
static String bitsToBytes(String geneString) {
    String geneString_temp = "", sub;

    for(int i = 0; i < geneString.length(); i = i+8) {
        sub = geneString.substring(i, i+8);

        if (sub.indexOf("\n") != -1) {
            if (sub.indexOf("\n") != geneString.length())
                sub = sub.substring(0, sub.indexOf("\n")) + sub.substring(sub.indexOf("\n")+1, sub.length()) + geneString.charAt(i+9);
        }

        byte octet = (byte) Integer.parseInt(sub, 2);

        System.out.println(octet);

        geneString_temp = geneString_temp + octet;
    }

    geneString = geneString_temp + "\n";

    return geneString;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `byte` is a *signed* type, meaning that when the most significant bit it set to `1`, the number is interpreted as negative.

This is precisely what happens when you print your byte here:

```
System.out.println(octet);
```

Since `PrintStream` does not have an overload of `println` that takes a single byte, the overload that takes an `int` gets called. Since `octet`'s most significant bit is set to `1`, the number gets sign-extended by replicating its sign bit into bits 9..32, resulting in printout of a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

`byte` is a signed [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer. So this is a normal behavior: the two's complement representation of a negative number has a 1 in the most-significant bit. You could think of it like a sign bit.

If you don't like this, you can use the following idiom:

```
System.out.println( octet & 0xFF );
```

This will pass the `byte` as an `int` while preventing sign extension. You'll get an output as if it were unsigned.

Java doesn't have unsigned types, so the only other thing you could do is store the numbers in a wider representation, e.g. `short`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all integers are signed, and the most significant bit is the sign bit.

Comment: Integers are two's compliment, so there's no sign bit.

Comment: You can tell the sign by the most significant bit, but it's not a "sign bit" in the same way floats have one.

Answer (score 0):

Because parseInt parse signed int that means it converts the binary if it begins with 0 its positive and if 1 its negative try to use parseUnsignedInt instead

Comment: It's not the parsing that turns the bytes negative, though. It's the `(byte)` casting conversion.